# Prepend text in file

Tags: linux, shell

I have used an awk command to find a particular line in a file and would like to prepend this in a second file. Can someone help me in this respect?

Comment: "Append" means attaching after. You cannot "append" something to the start of something else. There is a word for that: "[Prepend](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prepend)".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. You'll need a temp file.

```
echo "Prepended Line" > tmpfile && cat origfile >> tmpfile && mv tmpfile origfile
```

Edit:

```
sed -i 's/\(line you want\)/Prefix \1/g' origfile
```

Comment: This adds the text as first line and the previous first line as second line but I want to make it one line

Comment: That's a bit easier then. Edited.

Comment: +1 Also: `sed -i '/line you want/s/^/Prefix /g' origfile` or `sed -i '1s/^/Prefix /g' origfile` (the latter is based on the OP's self answer)

Answer (score 3):

Different ways to prepend a line:

```
(echo 'line to prepend';cat file)|sponge file
sed -i '1iline to prepend' file # GNU
sed -i '' $'1i\\\nline to prepend\n' file # BSD
printf %s\\n 0a 'line to prepend' . w|ed -s file
perl -pi -e 'print"line to prepend\n"if$.==1' file
```

Different ways to prepend a file:

```
cat file_to_prepend file|sponge file
{ rm file;cat file_to_prepend ->file; }<file
sed -i '1{h;s/.*/cat file_to_prepend/ep;g}' file # GNU
printf %s\\n '0r file_to_prepend' w|ed -s file
sed -i -e 1rfile_to_prepend -e '1{h;d}' -e '2{x;G}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd `cat(1)` the line into a dummy file, `cat` the second file in after it, and then overwrite the second file with the dummy. Look into the `sponge(1)` command, which lets you do the "natural" (but incorrect) `awk ... | cat - second-file > second-file`

Comment: I want to add the new line to the existing first line in the second file

Comment: The only solution accomplishing this in a single process.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(NR==1){print "text" $0}else{print }}' O/Pfile temp 
mv temp O/Pfile
```

Comment: Shorter: `awk 'NR==1{print "text" $0}' O/Pfile > temp; mv temp O/Pfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xclip (its primary selection) if you don't want to create a temporary file:

```bash
cat appendBefore.txt file.txt |xclip;xclip -o> file.txt
```